# UIWebView not freeing the memory on loading PDF files

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiwebview

> I am loading the pdf file (sizes: 15 MB) in UIWebView.

```
// If it is found, show it
[self.webView loadData:pdfData
              MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
      textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
               baseURL:nil];
```

**Problem is when I load the file many times the RAM usage goes higher and app crashesh at certain point. The occupied ram is not getting free when I pop the view controller.**

Comment: Instead of editing existing answers you can add your answer  separately.

Comment: that answer gave me clue, so i have modified that only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add three lines in your code and than check

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    [self.webview cleanForDealloc];
    self.webview = nil;
    [super dealloc];

}
```

**Update:**

Called below method when I remove the view controller.

```
-(void)webViewUnload {

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    [self.webView setDelegate:nil];
    [self.webView removeFromSuperview];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
}
```